# Git: add and commit if untracked or modified?

Tags: git, bash

What is the most acceptable way in a Bash script to add and commit to a Git repository files that exist and are untracked or changed?

`git add -A "$dir"` returns an error if the file does not exist, but returns 0 even if nothing was added. Then a subsequent `git commit -m "Update $dir"` might produce an error there is nothing to commit. My solution seems clunky, and I am not sure it is rigorous (in that `git add …` will never add anything when `git ls-files …` returns nothing):

```sh
[[ -n $(git ls-files --exclude-standard -om $dir) ]] &&
  git add -A "$dir" &&
  git commit -m "Update $dir"
```

**Fuller example**

This Bash script illustrates several functions to allow for a different commit message on initial commit of a file versus committing a change. Note it does not work well for directories since changed files as well as untracked files would be committed by `commit_if_untracked`. My current use case involves single files (thus `-A` below is unneeded, and `--exclude-standard` is arguably unneeded assuming I would want an error if I tried to commit a file that is ignored), but the above example with a directory was about as distilled as I could make an example!

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

main () {
  command_that_might_create_or_change_$file

  commit_if_untracked "$file" "Initial $file"
  commit_if_modified  "$file" "Update $file"
}

# Usage: commit_if_* <file> <msg>
commit_if_untracked () {
  # [[ $(git ls-files --exclude-standard -o) =~ ($'\n'|^)$1($'\n'|$) ]] || return 0
  [[ -n $(git ls-files --exclude-standard -o $1) ]] || return 0
  git add -A "$1" && git commit -m "$2"
}
commit_if_modified () {
  [[ -n $(git ls-files --exclude-standard -m $1) ]] || return 0
  git add -A "$1" && git commit -m "$2"
}
commit_if_untracked_or_modified () {
  [[ -n $(git ls-files --exclude-standard -om $1) ]] || return 0
  git add -A "$1" && git commit -m "$2"
}

main
```

Answer (score 1):

In writing this question I learned I could use `git status --porcelain` to shorten the code slightly. I am still hoping there is a better way.

For the first case that simply adds and commits only if there would be something to commit:

```sh
[[ -z $(git status --porcelain) ]] ||
  git add -A "$dir" && git commit -m "Update $dir"
```

To handle a different commit message depending on presence of untracked files that would be committed:

```sh
[[ ! $(git status --porcelain $dir) =~ (^|$'\n')\\?\\? ]] ||
  git add -A "$dir" && git commit -m "Initial $dir"
[[ -z $(git status --porcelain) ]] ||
  git add -A "$dir" && git commit -m "Update $dir"
```

Note the `[[ ! … ]] || …` could be slightly simplified to `[[ … ]] && …` if you are not using `set -o errexit`, or it could be written with `if` and `elif` to solve that issue and also avoid a redundant `git status` call if the first found untracked files:

```sh
if [[ $(git status --porcelain $dir) =~ (^|$'\n')\\?\\? ]]; then
  git add -A "$dir" && git commit -m "Initial $dir"
elif [[ -z $(git status --porcelain) ]]; then
  git add -A "$dir" && git commit -m "Update $dir"
fi
```